Did I accidentally delete the phone's data when activating Download mode using Odin?
A friend of mine asked me for some help with bringing back some lost data from his phone where there was an essential piece of information in it (his little son unwaveringly deleted it). It's been years since I tried that sort of thing, but I gave it a go.
I just read some people had varying degrees of success with third-party apps essentially using MOBILedit. I knew that, for it to have extended access to the phone's (Samsung Galaxy Z Fold4) memory, I had to set up root access for the phone. So I went to download the relevant firmware data (SMF 936B Turkey 2024-10-16 F936BXXS8GXIC, he bought the phone while on vacation in Turkey) and Odin. And before that, I had downloaded Magisk.
But when I activated download mode and set Odin to work, it just ended with failed. And after that, whatever effort I put in to get out of download mode, it didn't work. Now I'm stuck in download mode.
I need answers to two questions:

Does this mean I may have completely erased data from memory?
What should I do to fix this situation and get out of download mode?


First your approach was totally wrong. Rooting a phone requires unlocking the bootloader which permanently erases all crypto keys and all data in a away that it can never be recovered by anyone. What the problem is in your case it unknown.


You likely won't lose data if the flash fails.

To fix this, you should reflash the original firmware using Odin with Home CSC, which doesn't wipe data (unlike CSC).


Before attempting anything, if you encounter a failed flash in Odin and the device is stuck in download mode, hold the Volume Down and Power buttons to restart the device, which should typically bring you back to the lock screen.

Thank you very much. I just left all other fields empty except home_csc and it successfully resolved my situation. But when I tried to root it again, the error was raised right after this message:  ID:0/005 vbmeta_system.img
ID:0/005 FAIL! (Auth). I don't know why this happens.
